# Condicional para saber si variable es x veces mayor que otra variable

Tags: javascript

Con esta función:

```html
function test(){
  toReturn = 90;
  reference = 0;
  
  // haz cosas para lograr que reference sea igual a 90
}
```

Después de la función quiero hacer un condicional tan simple como

```
if (toReturn !== reference){
     haz x
}
```

Para filtrar cuando la función `test()` no logra poner el mismo valor a `reference` que el que tiene `toReturn`

El problema es que mi función es algo chapuza y nunca logra poner exactamente el valor de `toReturn` sino que pone algo así como 90.00005...etc Pero esto no me importa, me sirve. Pero entonces si pongo `toReturn !== reference` se va a cumplir siempre el condicional.

Quiero que sólo se cumpla cuando haya una diferencia de al menos, 1 o más (y no 0.1 por ejemplo) entre `toReturn` y `reference`. ¿Cómo hago eso?

```js
if (hay una diferencia de al menos 1 entre toReturn y reference){
    haz x
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ver la diferencia entre dos enteros la operación más sencilla es la división.

O sea, a/b te dirá cuántas veces es a mayor que b, pero te dará decimales.

Siempre puedes hacer `a/b > 1`

Dicho esto, si lo que quieres es un resultado entero a partir de decimales o sólo quieres quedarte con la parte entera del entero puedes hacer `Math.floor(x)`

Te dejo un snippet con distintas opciones que tienes:

```js
const timesBigger = (x, y) => x/y;

const trimDecimals = x => Math.floor(x);

const isTimesBigger = (num1, num2, times) => timesBigger(num1,num2) >= times;

const isEntirePartTimesBigger = (num1, num2, times) => trimDecimals(timesBigger(num1, num2)) >= times

const a = timesBigger(900, 16)
const b = trimDecimals(a);
const c = isTimesBigger(900, 16, 56);
const d = isEntirePartTimesBigger(900, 16, 56);

console.log(a, b, c, d);
```

De esta forma podrias hacer cualquiera de estas opciones:

- `toReturn/reference >= 1`
- `isTimesBigger(toReturn, reference, 1)`
- `isEntirePartTimesBigger(toReturn, reference, 1)`

Al final las dos últimas opciones son un encapsulador de la primera, te recomiendo sólo usar la primera, que es la más directa y los decimales contarán para la evaluación.

De todas formas, esto sólo te sirve para 90.00001 y no para 89.999999 que, como han comentado en otras respuestas también puedes hacer un [redondeo con respecto a un orden](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/262561/128321) en lugar del `Math.floor()`.

Answer (score 2):

Es típico perder precisión hacer hacer operaciones en coma flotante. Si sólo te interesa la parte entera, una solución sencilla es redondear el número:

```js
let n = 90.0001005;
console.log(n);

if (Math.round(n) === 90) {
  console.log('Conseguido');
}
```

Si quieres poder elegir el número de decimales, puedes hacer algo como:

```js
function redondea(num, decimales) {
   let orden= (10**decimales) // añadimos un cero por cada decimal que queremos
   let n= Math.round (num * orden);
   return n/orden; //quitamos los ceros tras redondear
}

console.log(redondea(1/3,2));
console.log(redondea(90.12345,2) == 90.12);
```